# Resolving a promise within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jsx

I am having trouble resolving this promise.

```js
const getAge = (actorId) => {
    return (
        axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/${actorId}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`)
            .then(function (response) {
              return moment().diff(response.data.birthday, 'years')
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
        )
    }

console.log(getAge('5000'), 'FUNCTION')
```

It doesnt ever resolve the promise and returns pending

[image]

I have tried a number of different ideas and none seem to work. What Am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. An async function always returns a promise. You can't use it to magically synchronise an asynchronous process.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to resolve in the code you have posted. Can you add that code? Common approaches include call backs, composition and async/await, but you can never return from a concurrent function. Hard to say what approach is the best without knowing what you are trying to do

Comment: add a then to getAge(5000) and you should be fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `.then` to get the value or wrap the call within a async function. For example:

```js
getAge('5000')
  .then(val => console.log(val, 'FUNCTION'));
```

Alternatively, wrapping with `async`:

```js
(async () => {
  const val = await getAge('5000');
  console.log(val, 'FUNCTION');
})();
```